# Plug-in types key value (UUID)

Tags: plugins, plist, macos-carbon, core-foundation

what is plugin-in types key value in plist file of plugin. it is another UUID or related to UUID used in plug-in factory interfaces key or item 0 value?  or its default value?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation says](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFPlugIns/Concepts/registration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001161-102762-BBCCCIHJ):

> Used for static registration. Its value should be a dictionary whose keys are type UUIDs and whose values are arrays of factory UUIDs.

So yes, each value in the types dictionary should be an array of UUIDs that are keys in the factory interfaces dictionary.

Comment: when i am changing plug-in types key value(5D4331DE-40AC-4DDF-B24F-B4D710CC9A61), its not working. why?

Comment: @ParagBafna: Because that UUID isn't in the interfaces dictionary, assuming it's the same project you showed in the question. Otherwise, you should ask a new question and show the Info.plist of the project you're working on now.

Comment: [Plugin is not working after changing plugin-type key value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9171964/plugin-is-not-working-after-changing-plugin-type-key-value)